# hibernate distinct clause not working

Tags: hibernate

i have this code

```
StatesProvinces statesProvinces = new StatesProvinces();
ArrayList<StatesProvinces> allStates = new ArrayList<StatesProvinces>();
ArrayList<String> states = new ArrayList<String>();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(StatesProvinces.class);
crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

List rsList = crit.list();
for (Iterator it = rsList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    statesProvinces = (StatesProvinces) it.next();
    allStates.add(statesProvinces);
    String state = statesProvinces.getState();
    states.add(state);
}
return states;
```

The result i am getting have the same state e.g Alaska 8 times, where it should be only 1 time for that i am using distinct above , but its not working ..where i am wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't have Alaska several times in this table, with several IDs?

Comment: The line "crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)" is wrong.  That tells Hibernate to give you back a list of all StatesProvinces with a unique ID.  You want a list with unique names.  Change your createCriteria code to the following:  session.createCriteria(StatesProvinces.class).setProjection( Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("name"), "name")))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StatesProvinces.class))
.list();

Answer (score 0):

the below code will give u list of unique states:

```
        Criteria criteria = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(StatesProvinces.class);
        ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("state"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projectionList));
        list = criteria.list();
```

The drawback of hibernate distict is we have to use it only with projections and in case we want the entire entity, we have to add projection to all fields and use setReusultTransformer as shown below:

criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StatesProvinces.class));